# How to reset keytab kerberos?

Tags: linux, kerberos

I am creating a shell script to reset the keytab storing multiple keytabs.
I thought to do it by deleting the Keytab and simply creating the new keytab.
Considering this approach might so I searched that below command removes the keytabs.

```
ipa-rmkeytab --realm EXAMPLE.COM --keytab /etc/krb5.keytab
```

I want to know if there is any alternative to the approaches.

Comment: What's wrong with that approach?

Comment: the mentioned command in question needs a package ipa_rmkeytab to install . I just wanted to know if thats the only solution to solve the problem?